# Slide anim android

Tags: android, animation

I have an homescreen with 2 buttons.
When i click a button I want to slide to the next activity.
I have 2 anim files:

1. slide in:

   ```
   <set xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">;
       <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" 
           android:toXDelta="0"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/> 
       <alpha
           android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
           android:toAlpha="1.0"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" /> 
   </set>
   ```
2. fade out:

   ```
   <set xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">; 
       <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50%p"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/> 
       <alpha 
           android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" /> 
   </set>
   ```

And my java code:

```
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

But when it slide, you see the left side goes from black to the second actvitiy.
Do you now how i can slide without that black side?

Comment: slide in:  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/> 
           <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
         </set>

Comment: slide out: <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50%p"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
        <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>

Answer (score 2):

I know you have the java code right (although you are using fade_in instead of slide in mentioned in the comments).

To slide in I've used this code in the past:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
android:fromXDelta="100%"
android:toXDelta="0%"
android:duration="600" />
</set>
```

And to slide out, it's just opposite:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
android:fromXDelta="0%"
android:toXDelta="-100%"
android:duration="600" />
</set>
```

That should work, tell me if it doesn't!